# Java - Drawing bitmaps is laggy

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am drawing my bitmaps to the screen using canvas and view. When I open up the screen I get a series of lags on the positioning of the image (almost as if I am watching the computer slowly think about where to place the points).

First like this:

[image]

Then:

[image]

And finally:

[image]

I understand it's kind of hard with the description I have given but if anyone has any idea could they please tell me!

**EDIT:**

```
public class LoseScreen extends View {

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    canvas.drawBitmap(box, null, menuBox, null);

    menuBox.set(screenWidth / 2 - menuWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2 - menuHeight / 2, menuBox.left + menuWidth, menuBox.top + menuHeight);
    tryagainBounds.set(screenWidth / 2 - tryagainWidth / 2, menuHeight / 2, tryagainBounds.left + tryagainWidth, tryagainBounds.top + tryagainHeight);


    canvas.drawText("    Score:", 100 * density, menuBox.top + 150 * density, finalScorePaint);
    canvas.drawText(finalScoreString, 225 * density, menuBox.top + 150 * density, finalScorePaint);

    canvas.drawText("Highscore:", 100 * density, menuBox.top + 200 * density, finalScorePaint);
    canvas.drawText(HighScore.toString(), 225 * density, menuBox.top + 200 * density, finalScorePaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tryagain, null, tryagainBounds, null);
```

Comment: Please add the code where you draw the bitmaps on the canvas, otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: Are you loading the bitmap on the main UI thread?

Comment: I added the code, and I dont know if I am loading it on the main UI thread, not sure what that means. I have multiple screens that load bitmaps if thats what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what your issue is without seeing any code.
But an idea could be to make sure you are using double buffering when drawing the image to the screen (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

Basic description of what this does: draws the image off the screen whilst it's being "built" and then move it to the view when it's complete. This won't however speed up the drawing process.